# jQuery event.target not working in firefox and IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on making an image slider that loads the image the user clicks on using jQuery. I have it working great in Chrome but when I tried it in firefox and IE it's not loading the image at all. Here's my code:

```
    $("img.clickable").click( function() {
    $("#image_slider").animate({opacity:1.0,left:200},"slow");
    $("#image_container").attr("src",event.target.src);
    ihidden = false;
});
```

When I try running this in firefox or IE it just doesn't load the image at all. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define the `event` in the arguments.

```
$("img.clickable").click( function(event) {
    $("#image_slider").animate({opacity:1.0,left:200},"slow");
    $("#image_container").attr("src",event.target.src);
    ihidden = false;
});
```

Otherwise it is going to use `window.event`.

Answer (score 1):

try using `$(this).attr('src')` instead of `event.target.src`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
target = (window.event) ? window.event.srcElement /* for IE */ : event.target
```

Comment: Not really desirable when jQuery already abstracts that away. You should also check for `target` first, with a fallback on `srcElement`.

Answer (score 0):

`$("img.clickable").click( function(e) {
    $("#image_slider").animate({opacity:1.0,left:200},"slow");
    $("#image_container").attr("src",$(e.target).attr('src'));
    ihidden = false;
});`

This should work just fine