# Event.Target not working in Firefox -- when fixed not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox

I am having the common issue in Firefox where `event.target` is undefined if you don't pass it in as an argument.

See these for reference:

[jQuery event.target not working in firefox and IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846446/jquery-event-target-not-working-in-firefox-and-ie)

[javascript event.target not working in mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051936/javascript-event-target-not-working-in-mozilla)

I am trying to get the checkbox that was checked inside a select list to determine what action to take.

My select list has the id of `#itemCategories`

According to the chrome debugger, and IE, before adding event it gets the correct element.

[image]

But after adding the event parameter `event.target` becomes the select list and not the selected item.

[image]

So the question comes down to what is the correct code for grabbing the selected element in a select list across all three major browsers (Chrome/IE/Firefox)

Comment: Maybe the original event will have the target you're looking for `event.originalEvent.target`. Or `event.currentTarget` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: If you watch the change event of a select, the event.target will get you the select object (what you call a list). What is the HTML corresponding to your #itemCategories ?

Comment: itemCategories is the select object `<select class="reportPagedropDowns" id="itemCategories" style="display: none;" multiple="multiple" selectedtext="#" noneselectedtext="Select" selected="" options="">`

Comment: `event.currentTarget` is the same as `event.target` when event is defined. `event.originalEvent` is undefined

Comment: Hi Mike, I've dealt a lot with check boxes and events.  My suggestion to you is to `.addClass()` `.on()` click and create your own argument behavior check.   Or, you add a layer on top of the entire list dynamically, and then "persist the click" only if the mouse if over the intended target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.addClass()` method has a callback which you can tap into.  If you combine it with jQuery psuedo selectors method you can target what was selected and it *should* be compatible across all browsers.  When different browsers behave differently with HTML elements, it is wisest to always use super specific `DOM` targeting that is normalized via jQuery.

**Documentation:**

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method

[.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method

[.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) method

[:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) method

```js
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/5754149/5076162
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/22648443/5076162
$('select').on("change", function() {
  $('select option:selected').addClass(function() {
    var isSelected = "isSelected";
    return isSelected;
  });
  var notSelected = $('select option').not($('select option:selected'));
  notSelected.removeClass('isSelected');
});
```

```css
select *.isSelected,
select *.isSelected {
  color: #ACE;
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="optionTest">
  <option value="volvo">Pick your car</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div>

</div>
```

```
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/5754149/5076162
$('select').on("change", function() {
  $('select option:selected').addClass(function() {
    var isSelected = "isSelected";
        return isSelected;
  });
    var notSelected = $('select option').not($('select option:selected'));
    notSelected.removeClass('isSelected');
});
```